# take powershell object save as xml and load in c#

Tags: c#, xml, powershell, dataset

I have the following powershell script that scans a location and adds the file details to a xml file,

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse c:\DATA | Select-Object  * , @{Name="Kbytes";Expression={ "{0:N0}" -f ($_.Length / 1Kb) }},@{Name="Age";Expression={ (((Get-Date) - $_.CreationTime).Days) }}  | Export-Clixml c:\DATA\Final.xml
```

As far as I understand this should be a object in the .net framework, assuming a dataset ?
what I would like to do is load this object into a c# application and use it as a dataset.

How would I load the object into a dataset in c# ?

Comment: By using Export-CliXML you are seriealizing the data. so, When you deserialize this, it won't be a live object. All the methods available on the object will be lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Add reference to the `System.Management.Automation.dll` assembly.
2. Create a PowerShell `Runspace`
3. Open the `Runspace`
4. Create a PowerShell `Pipeline` object with the `Import-CliXml` command
5. Invoke the `Pipeline`
6. Close the `Runspace`

   ```
       var rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
       rs.Open();
       var pl = rs.CreatePipeline(@"Import-CliXml c:\DATA\Final.xml;");
       var result = pl.Invoke();
       rs.Close();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

A faster approach might be:

-For lists

```
object[] xmlAsList =
     System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer.DeserializeAsList(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\batman\Desktop\myList.clixml"));
```

-For generic objects

```
object importedObject =
 System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer.Deserialize(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\batman\Desktop\myObject.clixml"));
```

Then, you manage the results via: `System.Management.Automation.PSObject` using the `Members` property.